# How to prevent a flask docker container from exiting when there are syntax errors?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a docker container running flask that is sharing it's /app directory. This is supposed to be a dev environment but sometimes when I'm working I will unknowingly save a python file with syntax errors which immediately causes the app to throw errors and exit. That's fine but since the docker container exits, I cannot reboot the flask app after fixing things. Any way to prevent this?

Here's the flask container, I'm guessing the CMD commands can be configured to prevent this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD app/ /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install flask
RUN pip3 install progress
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The container is supposed to exit if there are errors and you are supposed to run it again. Also, I recommend using the [offical python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) instead of vanilla ubuntu.

Comment: Why? This is a much simpler problem if you do development locally using a virtual environment, and only build the docker container once you're satisfied and tests pass.

Comment: What do you mean by do development locally? I'm not aware of a way to deploy flask without some type of virtualization. So if that's the case what makes docker worse than something else?

Answer (score 1):

You set that policy when you start the container using docker:

`docker run -d --restart always myimage:latest`

Or using docker-compose file you can add `restart: always` to your service definition.

```
  mycontainer:
    image: myimage:latest
    restart: always
    env: 
       ...
```